# Prevent .NET 7 Assembly Trimming Removes Constructors

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, msbuild

After upgrading my application to .NET 7, I'm having a problem with trimming. I use [MvvmDialogs](https://github.com/mysteryx93/HanumanInstitute.MvvmDialogs/) to manage dialogs which creates the views and windows from reflection. I'm the author of that library.

I was not having that problem before, but in .NET 7, I'm now having this issue:

> System.MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'HanumanInstitute.Converter432hz.Views.MainView'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.

It's removing the window constructor because it's only accessed via Reflection.

How can I solve this problem? And as the library author, what's the best advice I can give to those using the library, or the best way to solve that problem?

I did try setting `<IsTrimmable>false</IsTrimmable>` in the project but somehow I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: This would require every user of the library to annotate each and every Views of their project. Very prone to missing one. Not an ideal solution.

Comment: A bit naive here, but can't you force instantiation somehow om a "dummy"? Every soft reference issue can be solved by a hard reference, even if it's unpalatable.

Comment: Again that would require every library user to do this for every view. And with Avalonia Desktop/Mobile, each ViewModel has a View and a Window, doubling the affected classes. Let's imagine we got 20 pages in the app, so 40 affected classes, plus a few more in a helper library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to register the types into MvvmDialogs manually and avoid the need for reflection altogether.

It already has a ViewLocatorFactory design and I can probably implement this by creating a new Factory without needing to change the design at all.